# How to get Chromium to not deactivate the tab when inactive for 5 minutes programmatically in an Electron app?

Tags: google-chrome, electron, chromium

I have a LitElement single-page Electron application with a C#/.NET back-end running a Kestrel server that requests data from an external machine and returns a result that could include measurement data, informational data, etc. This request for data loops until the user stops the process of looping via a button. The users started complaining that the output on the page stops updating with new values after roughly 5 minutes of inactivity.

I discovered that at some point, Chromium added a memory management feature that disables tabs when they are inactive for roughly 5 minutes or so (unclear on the exact time). As long as some user activity occurs (e.g., mouse movement, etc.), this reactivates the tab which results in new data being updated on the page.

I am looking to see how to disable this memory management feature for tabs programmatically through Electron.

Versions:
LitElement v2.5.1
Electron v23.3.12
.NET 7

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Things that I tried**:

- **Electron app**:
- In main.js, I added this line of code:

```
 app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-features', 'TabSuspender');
```

- **In development environment (Chromium Browser without Electron)**:
- Disabled Calculate window occlusion on Windows
- In Settings -> Performance, disabled/enabled Memory Saver
- Added local URL to the Always keep these sites active section

All these attempts did not resolve the issue of keeping the tab alive so that the data display does not get interrupted.